# How to "compose" a number knowing its bits value in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to compose a 1-byte (`unsigned char`) number, knowing its bits value.

For example, 7th and 6th are always `0` and `1` respectively, values of 5th to 3rd are stored in three other variables, and 2nd to 0th bits shall take a value stored in one variable, e.g. decimal `5`.

At first I fought I can create an array of 8 elements, to store each bit, then convert it to a decimal number using custom `bin2dec`, but the problem is 1) I don't want to use additional "self-written" functions, 2) I'm not sure, how to put value `5` there (it looks like I need to `dec2bin` at first).

I can solve this problem using SystemC, but I'm interested how to do it using C/C++ methods (without additional downloaded libs).

Comment: Look up bit shifting.

Comment: `number = (0 << 7) | (1 << 6) | (v5 << 5) | (v3 << 3) | v20;`

Comment: Why not use [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: @Fredrik But they tagged it as a `c++`.

Comment: @Fredrik I don't see it. Where?

Comment: It’s in the title..

Comment: @Fredrik ... no? I mean, what do you mean?

Comment: The title literally says ”in C/C++”

Comment: @Fredrik Yes, exactly. "C/C++" is not a thing, so we can argue what exactly it means, but I'm sure it does not mean "the intersection of C and C++". When someone puts "C/C++" on their resume, it probably does not mean "I know the parts that C and C++ have in common".